# How does `echo` work in this context?: `externalip() { curl http://ipecho.net/plain; echo; }`

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, echo

While searching for a simple bash function that echoes my external IP address, I came across [this post](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-get-ip-address/), which had the following example:

```
function ext-ip () { curl http://ipecho.net/plain; echo; }
```

I'm wondering how `echo` works in this context; neither the `curl` nor the `echo` manpages were very helpful. Why does it echo the response body of the previous `curl` command? And is there any advantage to doing in this way as opposed to, e.g. `echo "$(curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain)"`? I'm only asking because the syntax of the latter seems more transparent/straightforward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why does it echo the response body of the previous `curl` command?

A classic *loaded question*.

It doesn't do any such thing.  The `curl` command outputs an IP address without a trailing newline.  The `echo` command supplies the newline.  It's that simple.

Whether

```
echo "$(curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain)"
```

is more straightforward than

```
curl http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
```

is a matter of taste to some extent.  It's worth noting, however, that `$()` is not available in the Bourne (not to be confused with the Bourne Again) shell nor in the C shells, whereas pretty much all shells can execute two plain commands in sequence separated by a semi-colon.  That even includes `csh` and `fish`.  ☺

Comment: Ahh, I feel silly now. Thanks for the detailed answer, as well as the additional information about the Bourne shell. :)